# Laravel Eloquent - Get all X through it's Y column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have a Thread model, which `hasMany` Post.
I want to get all Post that belongs to a certain thread.

However the `query` params sent to the controller is not `id`, but is the `'thread_name'` of the Thread.

What I'm doing right now is something like this:

1) Get the thread by `thread_name` (for argument sake, it's unique), which will give me `$thread`
2) Get all post where `thread_id = $thread->id`

I think this is not efficient because I'm sending doing two SQL queries.

Is there anyway to select the post through `thread_name`?

I'm sorry, I think this thread's title is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$thread = Thread::where('thread_name', $thread_name)->with('posts')->first();
```

This will load the posts of the thread into the Thread object.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the with method.